# global list did not update after append to it in local python

Tags: python

I am very new to python. I've faced some problems on my python program. 
I have created a global list, and I use it at local function to append another list. However, I have no idea why it didn't updated after finished running at local function.

My code:

```
temp_list = []

def callCounter(item):

    global c
    global temp_list

    c += Counter(item)
    for k,v in c.items():
        extracted_word.append(k)
        extracted_frequency.append(v)

        if k not in overall_words:
            overall_words.append(k)

    temp_list.append(extracted_word)

    extracted_word.clear()
    extracted_frequency.clear()
```

I have totally no idea on this....so weird

Comment: The way your code is formatted in the question isn't valid Python. You might want to fix the formatting, because right now it's not clear where you're modyfing `temp_list`. You also do not appear to ever be calling your `callCounter` function.

Comment: Please make your example self-contained. I don't know what result you expect and on top of that can't run it so I can't tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @Iarsks, this is just a function, I call it from my main program. And somehow, Could you give example to me as you said my code is not clear

Answer (score 0):

My expected result would be like this:

For the first loop,

```
extracted_word = ['you','are','good']
temp_list = [['you','are','good']]
```

For the second loop,

```
extracted_word = ['i','am','good']
temp_list = [['you','are','good'],['i','am','good']]
```

Comment: This is not an answer, this should be more information that you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46795552/edit) and add to your question.

Comment: Also, how to you run your code? There are many undefined variables, I can't get your code to run.